# Liferay 7 back to previous page

Tags: liferay

I am working with Liferay 7 and have a issue with back button like below image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvZD5.png)

Please suggestion me is this approach right? If not please suggest me any advice.

Thank you and best regards!

Comment: Can we keep the discussion in [a single place](https://web.liferay.com/en_GB/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/93454097) please? Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: I am sorry but I have not solved this issue yet by suggested solution in [posted question in Liferay forum](https://web.liferay.com/en_GB/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/93454097). Can you suggest me for another way?